# Autowire problem in mongo domain classes in Grails 4

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I need to autowire the SpringSecurityService inside a domain class but this code does not work.

This is the code of the entity:

```
class ActivityCondition extends SimpleCondition {

  static mapping = {
    autowire true
  }

  static transients = [
    'springSecurityService'
  ]

  SpringSecurityService springSecurityService

  // Other properties

}
```

I'm using Grails 4 with Gorm for MongoDB 7. This entity use a collection-per-hierarchy strategy.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `def springSecurityService` instead of `SpringSecurityService springSecurityService`. That worked for me.